# decimal with comma to string but with only 2 places after decimal

Tags: c#

I am getting decimal values in Webservice with **comma**.

Eg: 0,000 | 12,21365659697|11,125487654.

What i want is string but only with 2 values after comma.

**I tried**

Initilize-

```
decimal val=0m;
decimal val2=0m;
```

**Getting data from webservice and mapping to my field:**

```
"val": val = Convert.ToDecimal(GETDATA.GETDATA[0].GETDATA[i].GETDATA.N_VALUE);
```

And sending this value to my SQL with column defined as varchar after converting it to string .

```
public static string getdecimalSqlString(decimal decvar)
{            
    return decvar.ToString("#,##", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

I  assume this works well but my problem is if i do not get value ,then if I convert val2 with given condition,it will fail.

Also,if i use nullable decimal to initilize,i can not use formatting .

Thanks

**P.S.**-I may or may not get decimal(comma instead of decimal) and need string instead of decimal but with only 2 places after comma)

**Approach1**: is this right approach ?

```
  return decvar.ToString("#.##", new CultureInfo("en-US", true));
```

**Approach2** Or this one?

```
public static string getdecimalSqlString(decimal? decvar1)
        {
          string a=  decvar1.HasValue? decvar1.Value.ToString("#,##") : string.Empty;
            //return decvar.ToString("#.##", new CultureInfo("en-US", true));
            return a;
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question but if it fails converting use `Decimal.TryParse` in an `if` it will return false if it is not a decimal

Comment: In the ToString format, a `.` always means "the decimal character" and a `,` always means "the grouping character". It is then up to the Culture to provide the correct character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Web Service that returns a decimal value with a comma separator is a red flag.  Often it means the developer of the web service has formatted the string using the `CurrentCulture`, which happens to be a culture that has comma as a decimal separator.  And if so, moving the service to a server with a different culture may change the decimal separator it returns.

Therefore I would start by trying to confirm with the developer of the Web Service whether it is intentionally returning a comma separator, or whether it should be an invariant period separator.

To get the decimal value, you need to parse using the appropriate culture (`Culture.InvariantCulture` is probably best for a period separator, and an example of a culture that uses a comma separator is `new CultureInfo("fr-FR")`:

```
Decimal.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Number, myCulture, out result)
```

Once you have the decimal value, you can round to two decimal places using `Math.Round`.

Your code in getDecimalSqlString is wrong:

```
return decvar.ToString("#,##", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The format specifier should be "#.##" and if you want a comma separator you should specify a culture that uses one.

Finally, you say

> And sending this value to my SQL with column defined as varchar after converting it to string

In most cases, you should not be converting decimal to string before using it in an SQL query.  Instead, you should use a parameter with a decimal value in your query.

Comment: But i do not want to round the value,just need a string with 2 digit after  decimal or comma

Comment: Also,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture gets me the culture that uses comma seperator .i can try that but what happens if that value is blank,then i have initializes val as 0m.It will fail as i imagine

Comment: @poojaMalik - CultureInfo.InvariantCulture uses period as decimal separator (and comma as thousands separator.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will Helpful

```
public decimal _MFormatNo(string _value, int _pFractions = 2)
{
    decimal _pvalue = Convert.ToDecimal (_value.Remove(','));
    string _Format = ".";
    string Value = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < _pFractions; i++)
    {
        _Format += "0";
    }
    if (_pvalue == 0)
    {
        Value = "0" + _pvalue.ToString(_Format);
    }
    Value = (_pvalue).ToString(_Format);
    return Convert.ToDecimal(Value);
}
```

**UPDATE :**
As per OP requirement as she want string output

```
public string _MFormatNo(string _value, int _pFractions = 2)
{
    decimal _pvalue = Convert.ToDecimal(_value.Remove(','));
    string _Format = ".";
    string Value = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < _pFractions; i++)
    {
        _Format += "0";
    }
    if (_pvalue == 0)
    {
        Value = "0" + _pvalue.ToString(_Format);
    }
    Value = (_pvalue).ToString(_Format);
    return Value;
}
```

Comment: @poojaMalik, if we use ## then we will get only 2 fractions but with my code, it can take any no. of fractions

Comment: Thanks a lot.i will make the use and will post the result

Comment: In your updated code also,we are getting string but What i am getting is nullable decimal with comma.Well thanks a lot.i will make some changes and will update the outcome

Comment: @poojaMalik for nullable decimal check is null and assign 0 be fore decimal _pvalue = Convert.ToDecimal(_value.Remove(','));